# Area of Triangle inside another Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am stumped on the following question:

> > In the figure below $AD=4$ , $AB=3$ , and $CD=9$. What is the area of Triangle AEC?
> >     [image]

I need to solve this using trigonometric ratios however if trig. ratios makes this problem a lot easier to solve I would be interested in looking how that would work.
Currently I am attempting to solve this in the following way

$\bigtriangleup ACD_{Area}=\bigtriangleup ECD_{Area} + \bigtriangleup ACE_{Area}$

The only problem with this approach is finding the length of AE or ED. How would I do that ? Any suggestion or is there a better method

Comment: Consider using similar triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AE+ED=AD=4$, and $ECD$ and $EAB$ are similar (right?), so $AE$ is to $AB$ as $ED$ is to $CD$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks I believe I can take it from there .. though . How did you know that ECD and EAB are similar ?

Comment: They are right-angled, and share an angle at $E$ (so all corresponding pairs of angles are equal, so triangles are similar).

Comment: Angle-Angle. Thanks [This](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/triangles-similar-finding.html) helped

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  $\bigtriangleup DCE \sim \bigtriangleup ABE$ as $BC$ is crossing parallel lines.